# Add n number of days using simpledateformat in java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

We have a java code snippet here

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public class SimpleDateFormatExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date = new Date();
    int days = 5;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String strDate= formatter.format(date.getTime() + (days*86400000));
    System.out.println(strDate);
}
}
```

to add n no. of days to today's date. The result will be correct upto `n=24` but gives previous month' after `n=24`. Why it is so?

Comment: Do you have any hard requirements to use `Date`? Java8 provides [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) which will elegantly handle date adjustments

Comment: We are using in android app.

Comment: How about `Calendar`?

Comment: `Calender` can be used. But what is the wrong in above snippet?

Comment: There's also JodaTime if you're  < JDK8

Comment: Well, `Date` is outdated

Comment: In general, manipulations of dates and times are not done by adding milliseconds because there is no guarantee a day is `86400000` milliseconds (eg. when DST changes). Hence why `Calendar` is preferred. Or even better: use ThreeTenABP if you can.

Comment: @shinjw While Joda-Time is a step forward, [the ThreeTenABP library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) will be a still bigger step. It’s the Android edition of the backport of java.time. Joda-Time has been in maintenance mode for years now.

Comment: Related: [integer giving negative values in java in multiplication using positive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889828/integer-giving-negative-values-in-java-in-multiplication-using-positive-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `days*86400000L` to make this a `long` calculation otherwise the `int` value overflows.

Comment: Indeed a perfect solution for the question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the the `int is overflowing`

consider

```
    int days = 25;
    int d = days*86400000;
    System.out.println(d);
```

try

```
    int days = 25;
    long d = days*86400000L;
    System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate               // Represent a date-only, without a time-of-day and without a time zone.
.now()                  // Capture the current date, as seen through your JVM’s current default time zone. Better to pass a `ZoneId` as the optional argument.
.plusDays( 5 )          // Add five days, returning a new `LocalDate` object. Per the Immutable Objects pattern, a new object is produced rather than changing (“mutating”) the original.
.format(                // Generate text representing the date value of our `LocalDate` object.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) // Define a formatting pattern to suit your taste. Or call the `.ofLocalized…` methods to localize automatically. 
)                       // Returns a `String`.
```

## java.time

`Date` class represents a moment in UTC, a date with a time-of-day, and an offset-from-UTC of zero. Wrong class to use when working with date-only values.

Avoid using the terrible old legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar`, `Date`, and `SimpleDateFormat`. These classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Do not track days as a count of seconds or milliseconds. Days are not always 24 hours long, and years are not always 365 days long.

### `LocalDate`

Instead, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;
LocalDate later = today.plusDays( 5 ) ;
```

## Convert

Best to **avoid the legacy classes** altogether. But if you must interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time* classes, you can convert back-and-forth. Call new methods added to the old classes.

For `Date` you need to add a time-of-day. I expect you will want to go with the first moment of the day. And I'll assume you want to frame the date as UTC rather than a time zone. We must go through a `OffsetDateTime` object to add the time-of-day and offset. For the offset, we use the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`. Then we extract the more basic `Instant` class object to convert to a `java.util.Date`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( later , LocalTime.MIN , ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Combine the date with time-of-day and with an offset-from-UTC.
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;  // Convert to the more basic `Instant` class, a moment in UTC, always UTC by definition.
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;  // Convert from modern class to legacy class.
```

Going the other direction:

```
Instant instant = d.toInstant() ;  // Convert from legacy class to modern class.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in your code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 5); 

strDate = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes, you are right bro, but adding days using SimpleDateFormat sounds not very wise when we have Calendar. I just thought I need to come with another solution.